# И еще об арабских цифрах

Tags: цифры

В связи с предыдущим вопросом еще задумался, а почему те цифры, что мы употребляем, называются арабскими? Ничего ведь общего (ну, разве что девятка и единица более-менее)! Сравните сами:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У  индийцев  через  арабов  была   заимствована   система  счисления,  а  не  графика  цифровых  символов.  Графика  тех  символов,  которыми  мы  пользуемся,  сложилась  в  Европе,  уже  после  изобретения  книгопечатания.  См.  История  арифметики.  http://www.alleng.ru/d/math/math139.htm   Отсюда  можно  скачать.

Answer (score 2):

Цифры современной десятичной системы носят название арабских, поскольку европейцы заимствовали их у арабов. Однако, по данным многих исследователей, их родина - южная Индия. Они встречаются во множестве индийских документов начиная с V в. В этих документах уже используется десятичная система записи числа с ее простыми и удобными в написании цифрами (некоторые из них, хотя и не все, можно узнать и сейчас). Так что арабские цифры, «этот единственный универсальный язык нашего времени», ведут свое происхождение из Индии, хотя не исключено, что сама система счисления заимствовала кое-что из древнего Вавилона.  Индийская система счисления была революционной: индусы первыми в Старом свете стали употреблять ноль (в Новом независимо от них ноль открыт индейцами майя в Центральной Америке), что позволило удобно записывать числа в десятеричной системе. В целом индийская математика во многом благодаря этому открытию была одной из ведущих, именно поэтому в санскрите существуют словарные обозначения достаточно крупных чисел (миллиард и выше). 
Как раз эта теория находит свое место практически во всех исследовательских работах, со своей трактовкой.
Есть и другая версия, где автор утверждает, что арабские цифры - на самом деле русские. См.http://lubovinkin.narod.ru/arabskiecyfry.html